# How to Configure multiple network interfaces(eth0, eth1) in RHEL 7.3 OS

Tags: linux, networking, rhel7

I have tried to configure multiple Network interfaces in RHEL 7.3 VM. By default the machine comes up with ens32 and ens33 interfaces.But I want to change it as eth0 and eth1 respectively. 
Steps i have done:-
1. I have copied the file ifcfg-ens32 to ifcfg-eth0 and modified the Name as "eth0". Then I have deleted the ens32 and ens33 file. 
2. Regenerated the grub config file.
3. rebooted the machine.
At this point eth0 configured properly without any issue. it works fine.
Later I have tried to configure eth1 also. So I repeated the above steps for eth1. eth1 also configured but after some time i am unable to access the machine directly through putty. And from the VM, i am unable to ping the gateway also.

> route -vn 
>   o/p:

### Destination     | Gateway       |  Genmask        | Flags | Metric | Ref  |  Use | Iface

0.0.0.0         | 10.201.0.254  |  0.0.0.0        | UG    | 100  |  0    |    0 | eth0

0.0.0.0         | 10.201.0.254  |  0.0.0.0        | UG    | 101  | 0     |  0 | eth1

10.10.0.0       | 0.0.0.0       |  255.255.240.0  | U     | 100  |  0    |  0 | eth1

10.201.0.0      | 0.0.0.0       |  255.255.240.0  | U     | 100  |  0    |    0 | eth0

10.201.0.254    | 0.0.0.0       |  255.255.255.255| UH    | 100  |  0    |    0 |  eth1

My IT team suggested that the routing configuration itself is not proper. so they deleted some entries and then it works properly. after deleting the entries the tables looks like below:

> route -vn
>   o/p:

### Destination     | Gateway       |  Genmask        | Flags | Metric | Ref  |  Use | Iface

0.0.0.0         | 10.201.0.254  |  0.0.0.0        | UG    | 100  |  0    |    0 | eth0

10.10.0.0       | 0.0.0.0       |  255.255.240.0  | U     | 100  |  0    |  0 | eth1

10.201.0.0      | 0.0.0.0       |  255.255.240.0  | U     | 100  |  0    |    0 | eth0

After sometime again the same problem occurs. I am not aware all of this stuffs. I could not understand what happened here.How the new entries added. Am i configured the eth1 in proper way ? Need some body to help me in this. Thanks in advance.
Note: Our application runs in the same machine. It uses the eth1 as local heartbeat address.

Comment: What's wrong in this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello sheik,

```
        You are doing correct stuff. But my opinion
```

A) If u are assigning static IP:
   Then please check IP is already assign to someone

Solution 1: Use DHCP provided IP

Solution 2: please check IP already assign using arping

use this man page link
            https://linux.die.net/man/8/arping
            If we are getting reply it means that IP is already assign to someone.

Note: Don't use ping. Sometimes server not giving response to ping (i.e ICMP packets)
Thanks 
Best Luck...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response! but I have verified that there is no problem with static IP.

Comment: I am suspecting that it is because of our application. after running the application, the new entry gets added